# sharepoint graph api filtering based on a list column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-graph, graph-api

my query 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/lists/OEC_Docs?select=id,name,lastModifiedDateTime&expand=items(expand=fields(select=Title,Attachments,OptyNumber))&filter=items/OptyNumber eq '123'

fails with

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid filter clause",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f6426b70-ebe0-44ca-9439-34e1c94f19b0",
      "date": "2018-11-14T00:23:30"
    }
  }
}
```

where as without filter clause it works fine. based on docs it should work fine. please advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try filtering list items by using similar query as given below:

**For List on root site**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com/lists/MyListName/items?expand=fields(select=ID,OptyNumber)&filter=fields/OptyNumber eq '123'
```

**For List on subsite**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/mysite:/lists/MyListName/items?expand=fields(select=ID,OptyNumber)&filter=fields/OptyNumber eq '123'
```

**Note** : In case it gives an error to index the field on which you are filtering the list items, try adding an index to that field.

Source: [Add an index to a SharePoint column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0).

Comment: for me it still ends up with invalid filter clause. also notice that your list is not in the context of a site. this also seems to affect the query. as i need list of a site so even if above works my issue wont solve

Comment: my list is on root site

Comment: yes i know. but in my case query changes quite a lot after creating it under another site

Comment: Using similar to this `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/lists`, I am not able to get my subsite

Comment: Found it...see updated answer to query list from subsite.

Comment: now hitting ur index related issue. so query syntax is correct now. thanks. let me try to fix index as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85724/discussion-between-ganesh-sanap-and-vik).